# How to avoid increase in count when the repeater button clicked twice?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used a repeater button for show a set of videos. The issue is when the image button in the repeater is clicked twice the data base count is increasing twice.

I don't want that to be happening?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptVideos" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rpViewReports_ItemCommand">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table width="100%">
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 7%">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgRP" CommandName="Play" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ComponentId")%>'
                                runat="server" ImageUrl="../../../Images/VideoHelp.png"  />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span style="font-weight: bold"><%#Eval("ComponentName")%></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: this is not something that can do automatically with a flag - you need to add some javascript code to prevent double click submission

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following script in your aspx page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
   function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) { var oControl = args.get_postBackElement(); oControl.disabled = true; }

</script>
```

Or add the following code in your Page_load function ¨

```
 imgRP.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled='true';");
 imgRP.Attributes.Add("onload", "this.disabled='false';");
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. But still the count is increasing by 2

Comment: Thanks. But the code is working after first time click, (ie., At first it is allowing double click and the video loads, then if i press the same button next time its avoiding double click)